# regex to find a string that comes after =

Tags: javascript, regex

I´m really new to regex and I have been looking around to find an answer but either it dont work or I get some kind of error so I will try to ask the question and hopefulyl somebody can guide me through it :)

I have a string that can look like this:

> str = "car[brand=saab][wheels=4]"

I have no idea if you can get several different matches directly or if you need different .match() but anyhow.

I need everything before the first [] in 1 variable.

Then i need saab in another, and 4 in a third.

Comment: Are all the strings you wish to match in this format? are there always two groups of `[]`, or does it vary?

Comment: will there ever be more than 2 different attributes?

Comment: @melwil There can be 0 to several []

Comment: @emisal thg435's answer looks like it solves exactly what you want, you get the keywords and values into a map. There really isn't any better way to handle arbitrary groups in regex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a callback function is your tool of choice when parsing custom formats in javascript. Consider:

```
parse = function(s) {
    var result = {};
    s.replace(/^(\w+)|\[(.+?)=(.+?)\]/g, function($0, $1, $2, $3) {
        result[$2 || "kind"] = $1 || $3;
    });
    return result;
}
```

Example:

```
str = "car[brand=saab][wheels=4][price=1234][morestuff=foobar]"
console.log(parse(str))
// {"kind":"car","brand":"saab","wheels":"4","price":"1234","morestuff":"foobar"}
```

Comment: It should work, but the downside is that replace() isn't syntactically meant to use it like this. I find .match() with a postprocessor function still a better fit.

Comment: @Willem Mulder Could you explain what you mean by replace() isn't syntactically meant to be used like this and what problems it could cause?

Comment: Thanks for the answer it works great, but I just realized that it would work better if I had this on the c# side of my code instead of the Javascript side. So if you want to and know c# could you convert your answer to c# in my new question that is exactly the same but just in c# :)

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788198/c-sharp-regex-to-find-a-string-that-comes-after)

Comment: @emisal the .replace() function is meant to replace text, whereas you don't want to replace text, you want to find/match text. Thus, the .match() function is a better fit. See e.g. my answer on how that works.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex:

```
([^\[]*)\[[^=]+=([^\]]*)\]\[[^=]+=([^\]]*)\]
```

You can then grap matching group #1, #2 and #3

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/XNZfHcMAp8

In Javascript:

```
str = 'car[brand=saab][wheels=4]';
console.log('match::' + str.match(/([^[]*)\[[^=]+=([^\]]*)\]\[[^=]+=([^\]]*)\]/));
```

Comment: I beleive the test string is actually `car[brand=saab][wheels=4]` rather than `str = "car[brand=saab][wheels=4]"`

Comment: This is too specific : it matches only the things with 2 groups (`[a=b][c=d]`, but sadly no things like `[a=b]` or `[a=b][c=d][e=f]`)

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work :

```
([^[]+)(?:\[[^=]+=([^\]]+)\])+
```

*Explainations :*

`([^[])` First, you match everything that is not a [.

`(?:...)+` Then, when you find it, you're starting repeting a pattern

`\[[^=]` Find everything that is not an =, and discard it.

`([^\]])` Find everything that is not a ] and capture it.

Comment: I'd say you're missing at least a few "+" signs in there ;)

Comment: You're also missing a `=` after the `[^=]+`. The rest would not match otherwise. :)

Comment: What @blue112 currently has will only return `car` and `=4`, with @Talus change it will still only return `car` and `4` (no `saab`)

Comment: indeed, I think it should need some recursion... Like [the other answer proposed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16775949/624544) by @thg435

Answer (score 1):

```
/([^\[]+)\[brand=([^\]]+)\]\[wheels=(\d)\]/
```

Works.

Try it like

```
var result = "car[brand=saab][wheels=4]".match(/([^\[]+)\[brand=([^\]]+)\]\[wheels=(\d)\]/)
```

Result would be

```
[ "car[brand=saab][wheels=4]", "car", "saab", "4" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do it with match in one shot, and get an array back.

below lines were tested in chrome console:

```
str = "car[brand=saab][wheels=4]";
"car[brand=saab][wheels=4]"
str.match(/[^=[\]]+(?=[[\]])/g)
["car", "saab", "4"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getObject(str) {

    var props = str.split(/\[(.*?)\]/g),
        object = {};
    if (props.length) {
        object.name = props.shift();
        while (props.length) {
            var prop = props.shift().split("=");
            if(prop.length == 2){
                object[prop[0]] = prop[1];
            }
        }
    }
    return object;
}

console.log(getObject("car[brand=saab][wheels=4]"));
```