# c# - regex to find a string that comes after =

Tags: c#, regex

So I asked this question before and said I wanted it in javascript but realized later on that it's unecessary data being sent. So it would be great if anybody could help me solve the same thing in C#

What I need is to get several properties out of a string.

The string will look something like:

```
str = "car[brand=saab][wheels=4]";
```

There can be more or fewer properties.

I need everything before the first [] in 1 variable.

Then I need each property and its value in a variable.

Easiest way to understand what I want is probably to check my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775556/regex-to-find-a-string-that-comes-after/16775949#16775949) and the answer that solved it :)

Comment: If you have so many question about finding a pattern in a string, maybe you should look at a book about RegEx yourself.

Comment: Does this *have* to be done with a regular expression?

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih I'm trying to learn RegEx as i go along but i got a really tight schedule. And I'm a novice programmer so I kinda have to learn as I type. That's why I ask questions instead of reading books, and secondly reading books about programming don't really work for me :(

Comment: @DaveRook No it dont have to be regex I just thought it was the easier way to do it.

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih Yeah I know that the RegEx works fine in that one but I don't really understand what the function does and thus I cant write it in c#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the regex(slightly different) in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775556/regex-to-find-a-string-that-comes-after/16775949#16775949).

```
string input = "car[brand=saab][wheels=4]";

string product = "";
Dictionary<string, string> props = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, @"^(\w+)|\[(\w+)=(.+?)\]"))
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(product))
        product = m.Groups[1].Value;
    else
        props.Add(m.Groups[2].Value, m.Groups[3].Value);
}
```

Comment: Yet this one is the only correct among all answers ( except mine ^_^)

Comment: This fixed exactly what I needed just had to change so the product was added to the Dictionary as well. 

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

try this regex:

```
(.+?)(\[.+?\])+
```

and a sample code:

```
var inputString = "car[brand=saab][wheels=4]";
var pattern = @"(?<v1>.+?)(?<v2>\[.+?\])+";

var v1 = Regex.Match(inputString, pattern).Groups["v1"].Value;

Dictionary<String, String> list = new Dictionary<String, String>();
foreach (Capture capture in Regex.Match(inputString, pattern).Groups["v2"].Captures)
{
    var sp = capture.Value.Split('=');
    list.Add(sp[0], sp[1]);
}
```

explain:

> ***`(?<name>subexpression)`***
>   Captures the matched subexpression into a named group.

Comment: This is actually not quite the same that author asks for

Comment: Won't `v2` also contain the square brackets as part of the capturing group?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
var lst=Regex.Matches(input,@"(\w+)((?:\[.*?\])+)")
             .Cast<Match>()
             .Select(x=>new
             {
                 name=x.Groups[1].Value,
                 value=Regex.Matches(x.Groups[2].Value,@"(?<=\[).*?(?=\])")
                            .Cast<Match>()
                            .Select(x=>new
                            {
                                 name=x.Groups[0].Value.Split('=')[0],
                                 value=x.Groups[0].Value.Split('=')[1]
                            })
             });
```

---

Now you can iterate over lst like this

```
foreach(var parent in lst)
{
parent.name;//car
   foreach(var pairs in parent.value)
   {
        pairs.name;//brand,wheels
        pairs.value;//ferrari,4
    }
}
```

---

So,for input `car[brand=a][wheels=4]cycle[brand=b][wheels=2]`

Output would be like

```
car
   brand,a
   wheels,4
cycle
   brand,b
   wheels,2
```

Comment: This is wrong. After correcting all mistakes the output is still incorrect. Ideone: http://ideone.com/1bIPZA

Comment: http://ideone.com/SswaUI still incorrect) But almost there)

Comment: I got exception http://ideone.com/ZFcxst. Probably mono-2.8 problems, but I get the same error in LinqPad =)

Comment: PS: I am not the TS and I know the solution, I just want to come up with this answer to make it correct and give you an upvote

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have an answer using regex and your comments state it doesn't have to be with a regex, I'll offer an alternative:

The code is

```
        string str = ("car[brand=saab][wheels=4]");
        int i = str.IndexOf("[");

        string[] details =str.Substring(i).Replace("]","").Split('[');

        string name = str.Substring(0, i);
        string brand = details[1].Split('=')[1];
        string wheels = details[2].Split('=')[1];
```

This approach assumes the data is always going to be in the same format though; you may need some validation in there depending on your needs...

Answer (score 0):

Without regex:

```
string input = "car[brand=saab][wheels=4]";

var query = from s in input.Replace("]", "").Split('[')
            let vars = s.Split('=')
            let name = vars[0]
            let value = vars.Length > 1 ? vars[1] : ""
            select new {Name = name, Value = value};

string firstVar = query.First().Name;
Dictionary<string, string> otherVars = query
                                        .Skip(1)
                                        .ToDictionary(v => v.Name, v => v.Value);
```

You can access your variables in the dictionary like this `string brand = otherVars["brand"]`